# Expose csrf token to the client that is on a different domain

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, csrf, nuxt.js

I'm using the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf to protect my public routes against cross-site request forgery. The server and client are hosted on two different domains, so I can't use the direct way to pass the generated token to the client.

I've created now two different endpoints on the server, /csrfToken is sending the generated token and the csrf cookie within the headers and the route /register must verify the given token and csrf cookie if it's correct.

```
const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 900
  }
})

router.get('/csrfToken', csrfProtection, async (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ token: req.csrfToken() });
});

router.post(
  '/register',
  csrfProtection,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    return res.send('user registered');
  }
);
```

The problem that I'm facing now is that the endpoint /csrfToken is open for all public request and everyone can make a request to it. So is there a way that I can get the token without exposing the credentials to the client?

I'm using nuxt/vue, if thats relevant for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are exposing the token as JSON, you are presumably making these requests using Ajax.

Just makes sure that your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header allows only *your* website to read the data from it.

Then, while anyone could make a request to the endpoint through a non-Ajax HTTP client, it wouldn't be able to use it to perform a CSRF attack because their token wouldn't match the one in the user's cookie.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ajax for the requests. I've already set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in node: 
    
`app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
   credentials: true
}));`

So basically everyone can make requests to my application for example through postman (which i assume is a non-Ajax HTTP client), but when someone is trying to make csrf attacks they always have to be on a Ajax HTTP client?

Comment: @ProV — A CSRF attack involves a third party persuading an authenticated user's browser to make a request to a server which does something harmful. If there is a CSRF defence in place, they can't do that without knowing the CSRF token which **matches** the one in the user's cookie. If they use Postman, they'll get a token of their own, but it won't match some other user.

Comment: Okay and if I wan't additionaly that the client is not overusing his token for creating to much requests to my endpoint? Do you suggest to use something like this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit